# Rashberry Pi: No-ip - Cannot access ssh

Tags: ssh, linux, dns

I am setting up DDNS for my Rashberry Pi to access from anywhere, followed the [instruction](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/install-ip-duc-onto-raspberry-pi/)

All seems good after setup, but I cannot access Rashberry Pi with ssh

My command in terminal:

```
ssh pi@xxxx.no-ip.domain
```

I type the pi's password, but it replies "Permission denied"

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: And you have enabled ssh? It is disabled by default in more recent versions of Raspbian.

Comment: I have no error of ssh with the router IP, ssh pi@192.168.1.xxx (which point to Rashberry Pi). But I recieved "Permission denied" with hostname (no-ip)

Comment: Maybe try to run it with `sudo` in front.

Comment: @Flajt You don't need special permission to run `ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you arrive at the password prompt, DDNS's part is over - the ball is in your court.

Can you copy-paste here a verbatim example of what you are doing in the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

You have to forward port 22 on your router

Comment: If he is getting a permission denied error communication is unlikely to be the cause.